# Prove that $(X,||.||_0)$ is banach space. where $||x||_0=||y||+||z||$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,||.||)$ a banach space. Let $Y,Z$ closed subspaces of $X$ such that $X=Y\oplus Z$ (algebraic direct sum). For $x=y+z$ with $y\in Y$ and $z\in Z$ we define:

$$||x||_0=||y||+||z||$$

Prove that $(X,||.||_0)$ is banach space.

**My attempt:**

Let $\{x_n\}\subset X$ with norm $||.||_0$ a cauchy sequence.
As $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subset of $X$ and $(X,||.||)$ is a banach space, then $Y,Z$ are banach.

Let $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m>N$ then $$||x_n-x_m||_0<\epsilon$$

Moreover,
$$||x_n-x_m||_0=||y_n-y_m||+||z_n-z_m||<\epsilon$$

This implies:
$$||y_n-y_m||<\epsilon\tag1$$
$$||z_n-z_m||<\epsilon\tag2$$

Then, $\{y_n\}$,$\{z_n\}$ are cauchy sequences in $Y,Z$.

As $Y,Z$ are banach spaces then $y_n\rightarrow y$  and $z_n\rightarrow z$ where$y\in Y$ and $z\in Z$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: Just show that $\|x_n - (y+z)\|_0 \to 0$

Comment: You should say the obvious, that you're writing $x_n = (y_n,z_n)$.